# Registering custom importer. ImportExport`RegisterImport is not recognized

Tags: import

I tried to follow the original example from Wolfram Docs to design my own `Import`-er for the custom format I have.

See the [original example](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RegisterFormat) here

So here is the code

```mathematica
ResourceFunction["RegisterFormat"]["myFmt", <|"Extensions" -> "myext"|>]

myFormatImport[filename_String, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := filename;
ImportExport`RegisterImport["myFmt", myFormatImport];

Import["test.myext"]
```

In principle it should immediately return the filename, however it only shows
[image]

Moreover, Mathematica does not highlight the key function here

[image]

Own values are empty as well.

Has anyone faced similar issue?

Mathematica Student Edition 13.0
MacOS

Comment: Are you sure the file exist in the correct directory? Does giving the full path to `Import` help?

Comment: @Domen, that's a trick. I wanted Mathematica to use my function to check if file exists

Comment: Doesn't matter if the function has `OwnValues`, you want to check the `DownValues`. Moreover `Import` does a bunch of checking/pre-validation that I don't think you can circumvent as it delegates to ``System`ConvertersDump`ImportTest``

Comment: Thanks @b3m2a1 for the explanation. So i ended up using just a custom function for that. Sad, that ‘Import’ is hardwired so much. I originally planned to implement caching and many other stuff on that, thats the reason why i wanted to override it, so it won’t event try to use IO before my pipeline.